# i got an error.Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).when i give listitem.BreakRoleInheritance(false)

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

I setting permission to list item customlly.But i got a error:

`"Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))" .`

```
 if (!listitem.HasUniqueRoleAssignments) 
 { 
    listitem.BreakRoleInheritance(false);//I got an error here 
 }
```

Please help me..

Comment: Are you running with elevated privileges?

Answer (score 0):

Calling this code will require that the user have permissions to change the list settings or more even. The use of a [RunWithElevatedPrivileges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsecurity.runwithelevatedprivileges.aspx) delegate will run the code as if it were using the identity of the Application Pool.

It is possible to check to see if the user has permission to make this change, but that lookup requires a permission level more than just a normal user to call, so the easy answer is to just wrap your code with a RunWithElevatedPrivileges delegate.